how to pull particular string, when multiple pattern matches using regexp in oracle
I am trying to extract data related to string 'HP', using regexp functions, but it's not working as expected.
Scenario 1

¶¿  current reading is not ready for HP (by device). Unable to assess. ¶¿ reading again checked this time and it is HP of 70.2 looks its normal. Normal readings in function.

Sceanario 2

There was appropriate HP is 80-90% of the total. New readings will not required.

Sceanario 3

Readings for HP are bad. New HP readings for 2 and 3 round will be taken next week. HP reading will be >50, data is fine.

I have tried the below approach but its not woking for all scenarios:
SUBSTR(
  test_data,
  regexp_instr(
    test_data,
    '(*) HP (*)',1,1,0,'i'
  ),
  regexp_instr(
    SUBSTR(
      test_data,
      regexp_instr(
        test_data,
        '(*) HP (*)',1,1,0,'i'
      )
    ),
    '(*)%(*)',1,1,0,'i'
  )
)

Expected answers for above 3 scenarios:
|70.2 |
|80-90| 
|50   |


* is a quantifier, you need .* or .*?
